# Unable to call component method. Public method [display] not found on component

Tags: laravel-livewire

Hello I'm following tutorials on toggle switch button from laravel livewire the display value is showing and working fine but when I click the switch it shows up an error or make any changes in the switch button it always says public method display is not found but the value read on the button and displaying fine
here's the component

```
public Model $model;
    
    public $field;

    public bool $display;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->display = (bool) $this->model->getAttribute($this->field);
    }

    public function updating($field, $value)
    {
        dd($value, $this->field);
        $this->model->setAttribute($this->field, $value)->save();
        $this->emit('statusUpdated'); // this emit is used for show status changed message for this import or use cdn of Alpine Js also
    }
```

the view component

```
<div>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" wire:change='display' @if($display) checked @endif> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried dd method but it doesn't work it shows the error right away appreciate any help thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wire:model` rather than `wire:change`, and remove `@if($display) checked @endif`

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" wire:model='display'>
```

`wire:model` is used for binding the data, while `wire:change` is for binding a method on the component to the change-event.